# Angular 2 Testing Input Box Binding

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I can't seem to test an input box bound to an Angluar2 model. I'm a little new to this so please bear with me.

I have a very basic Angular2 component which contains an inputbox bound to a model.

```
<form>
    <input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" name="termsearchTerm" (keyup)="search()"  value=""/>
</form>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'sc-search',
    templateUrl: 'search.component.html'
})

export class SearchComponent {
    @Input() data: any;
    @Output() onSearchTermChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();
    private searchTerm: string;

    search() {
        this.onSearchTermChanged.emit(this.searchTerm);
    }
}
```

When running the following test keep getting Expected undefined to equal 'John'.
I'm expecting the test to pass.

```
 searchableHierarchyComponentFixture.detectChanges();

    let termInputDbg = searchableHierarchyComponentFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name="termsearchTerm"]'));
    let input = searchableHierarchyComponentFixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');

    input.value = 'John';

    let evt = document.createEvent('Event');
    evt.initEvent('keyup', true, false);

    termInputDbg.triggerEventHandler('keyup', null);
    input.dispatchEvent(evt);


    tick(50);
    searchableHierarchyComponentFixture.detectChanges();
    searchableHierarchyComponentFixture.whenStable();
    expect(searchableHierarchyComponentFixture.componentInstance.searchTerm).toEqual('John');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So a couple things:

1. You need to call `tick` after the component is created. Not completely sure, but I think the model binding happens asynchronously. Without ticking, the test will fail.
2. The directive listens for the `input` event, not the `keyup`. When the `input` event occurs, the directive updates the bindings.

Here's a complete test (also on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RGRniXH0oDYdVK9HteK3?p=preview))

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `
    <form>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="query" name="query" />
    </form>
  `
})
class TestComponent {
  query: string;
}

describe('TestComponent: ngModel', () => {

  let fixture;
  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      declarations: [TestComponent]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should change the value', fakeAsync(() => {
    let input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;

    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();

    expect(component.query).toBeFalsy();

    input.value = 'Hello World';
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    tick();

    expect(component.query).toBe('Hello World');

  }));
});
```

**See also**

- When in doubt, sometimes the best place to look for examples is the [source code tests](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/test/template_integration_spec.ts)

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you!

Comment: Hey guys, like an answer and the question itself. but what is tick function here? I have same situation now. and want to test ngModel bound to the input. do I need that tick()?

Comment: @JanatbekSharsheyev For input test, yes you will need it. If you're not sure what it is , see the angular docs for testing. There's a section on asynchronous testing

Comment: Paul's link has moved here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/test/template_integration_spec.ts